# UIButton title set in Storyboard is missing when run

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I am quite new to iOS development and I encountered a problem when I was trying out a simple calculator tutorial. For some reason, the "0" and "=" does not appear on the iOS simulator while it appeared perfectly fine on the user interface shown on XCode.

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks! =)

[image]

Comment: Can you check the size of the text? It may be bigger than the button can fit.

Comment: Have you written any code dealing with these buttons? If so, please show it.

Comment: @hw731, nope. I have not written any codes dealing with the buttons at all.

Comment: @heinst the size of the text is 15 which should be able to fit in the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility could be that you accidentally set the titles of those two buttons on a control state other than default or `UIControlStateNormal`.

The buttons in your screenshot are in a state called `UIControlStateNormal` because they aren't being tapped or disabled. Select the buttons and make sure the 'State Config' option in the Attributes inspector is set to 'Default' when you're setting your title in Storyboard.

**EDIT**

Autolayout sometimes causes unintended behavior like this. If you aren't relying on Autolayout and don't plan to, you can turn it off in the File inspector. If you are relying on Autolayout, you'll have to write some code to undo the unintended behavior it's causing.

Comment: Hi there,

I remove the 2 buttons and added in new buttons. They are both set to 'Default' in the 'State Config' option. Still having the same result. See the image.
http://i.imgur.com/GikFSws.png

Comment: From that image, it looks like there is some type of ellipses on the 0 button now.

Comment: Yup. I tried googling for solutions. I stumbled upon something called auto resize? You have any ideas?

Comment: Yes try selecting the view controller, selecting the File inspector on the right hand side, and unchecking "Use Auto-layout"

Comment: there should be an option to turn that off, if you click on the button it should be somewhere on the right hand pane.

Comment: I found it. It worked. Thanks! =D
Any reason on why this happened?

Comment: Autolayout sometimes causes some unintended behavior. Hopefully it gets better in iOS 7. I'll update my answer to the correct solution.

Comment: I see. Sure! Thanks! I will set your answer to the accepted answer when you update it.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the Style value to **"Default"** from **"Attributes Inspector"** tab as shown in the image below.

[image]

**Now you should see the Font, Color and other attributed properties are back :)**

Answer (score 1):

In my case the button title disappeared, when I made changes to its attributes. Changing the Button title back to 'plain' and back again to 'attributed' made the text visible again.